# 32 column limit for grouping sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, grouping-sets

I am still working on sql 2005 to sql 2014 server migration.

With the older server, using `COMPUTE BY`, I was able to create a report that had 57 columns with some of those column being aggregate fields. There was no limit to the amount of columns I can use in one report(one query).

With the new sql 2014, I am using `grouping sets` to get the same results but I run into a limitation. I cannot put all my columns into one grouping set and then get the subtotals and the grand total:

> Too many expressions are specified in the
>   GROUP BY clause. The maximum number is 32 when grouping sets are
>   supplied.

Is there a way I can supply more columns or is there a way around this limitation?

I have also attached the image to better understand what is going on..[Query image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d2Aj.png)

Comment: More than 32 columns is an awful lot of columns for a table with subtotals.  Perhaps not all are needed for aggregation.

Comment: Not all of them are aggregated columns, yet " grouping set" requires to add them all.

Comment: . . Consider using `MAX(col) as col` instead of `col` in the `GROUP BY` clauses, for columns that do not need to be aggregated.

Comment: Can you kind of explain what you mean? I will add my query to my original post to better understand what I am asking for

Comment: This screams, SSAS solution with dimensions needed... I think you're trying to do too much with OLTP. 

Reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190452(v=sql.105).aspx

If it were me, i'd suggest breaking it out into multiple queries as a short-term solution and express the need for an OLAP solution if this kind of thing is common where you work.

Comment: The thing is that query gets built dynamically on the fly for the reporting web site. That particular report needs all those columns and I need to find some sort of solution to make it still work with new sql 2014